# Auto Create Parse app

Tags: parse-platform, autodeploy

We are working on a product. For each customer approached us, we would auto deploy iOS & Android apps to respective play stores. These apps would be associated with separate Parse app as back end. Is there any way to create the Parse app via APIs automatically instead of creating manually & after auto-creation,  associate it to the apps before they are deployed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

As described [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#apps-creating-apps), just send a POST request to `/1/apps` endpoint.

Example:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Email: <PARSE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>" \
  -H "X-Parse-Password: <PARSE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"appName":"my new app","clientClassCreationEnabled":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/apps
```